# Developed Society For Quirk Users?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So I've seen a lot of fanart and headcanons of Fumikage Tokoyami showing (or stating) that he has trouble drinking using certain cups, and of Kirishima flossing his teeth. With the development of inhumane features being a norm in everyday society, you'd think that there are certain products made for people with bodily mutations.

Is there any proof of this in the anime or manga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Check out episode 38 when Deku and most of his classmates go to the mall! It's mentioned that there are clothing products for every unique body type.